# I need search a pattern in a header line of my file and concatenates the next line with Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, fasta, dna-sequence

My multi-fasta archive is in this format:

```
>miRNA65 dvex2345
CGATGCTAGATGCTATGACAACGATGCCTCG-G
>miRNA60 dvex1234
T-TAA-ACTCATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG
>miRNA65 dvex2345
T-TAA-ACTTATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG
```

I am new in Perl and I need to search the equals '> lines' and concatenate the next line to join the sequence.

I'm expecting the following output for the above file:

```
>miRNA60 dvex1234
T-TAA-ACTCATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG
>miRNA65 dvex2345
T-TAA-ACTTATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG.CGATGCTAGATGCTATGACAACGATGCCTCG-G
```

What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%hash;
while (<DATA>) {
        if (/^>(miRNA\d+)/) {
                $hash{$1}[0] = $_;
                chomp($n = <DATA>);
                unshift @{$hash{$1}[1]}, $n;
        }
}

for $k (sort keys %hash) {
        print $hash{$k}[0], join(',', @{$hash{$k}[1]}), "\n";
}
__DATA__
>miRNA65 dvex2345
CGATGCTAGATGCTATGACAACGATGCCTCG-G
>miRNA60 dvex1234
T-TAA-ACTCATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG
>miRNA65 dvex2345
T-TAA-ACTTATCATCATCATACTCATCATCATCATCAGCATATTAACAAG
```