# Concatenating Multiple Sequences for a Sample within FASTA file using Perl and REGEX

Tags: regex, perl, concatenation, fasta

I have over 200 multi-sequence fasta files and inside each fasta file, there are sequences for hundreds of samples for a select gene (i.e.PF3D7_1467550 in the sample input fasta file). Most samples (i.e. sample 303.1 - first sequence in the sample input file) within a fasta file have one sequence but other samples (i.e. IGS-MLW-089sA and IGS-MWI-254sA) have multiple sequences for a gene that need to be concatenated together.

Sample input fasta file

```
>303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:126].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
EEKKTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVI
KNVQ

>IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
>IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[65:126].sp.tr
TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVIKNVQ

>IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
>IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[65:119].sp.tr
TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDC
```

Desired output:

```
 >303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:126].sp.tr
 MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
 EEKKTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVI
 KNVQ

 >IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61][65:126].sp.tr
 MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
 TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVIKNVQ

 >IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61][65:119].sp.tr
 MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
 TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDC
```

I believe this code from another ticket could be useful.

```
 %hash;
 while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^>(miRNA\d+)/) {
            $hash{$1}[0] = $_;
            chomp($n = <DATA>);
            unshift @{$hash{$1}[1]}, $n;
    }
}

for $k (sort keys %hash) {
    print $hash{$k}[0], join(',', @{$hash{$k}[1]}), "\n";
 }
```

Here is the link to the previous ticket:

[I need search a pattern in a header line of my file and concatenates the next line with Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821962/i-need-search-a-pattern-in-a-header-line-of-my-file-and-concatenates-the-next-li)

I am looking for help to modify the following part of code dealing with the selecting the sampleID or alternative suggestions.

```
 /^>(miRNA\d+)/
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If the samples to be concatenated are adjacent, you can just collect the ranges (e.g. `[1:61]`) and lines to be printed in two arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

sub without_ranges {
    my ($header) = @_;
    ( my $without = $header ) =~ s/\[[^\]]+\]//g;
    return $without
}

sub output {
    my ($header, $ranges, $buffer) = @_;
    my $header_with_ranges = $header;
    $header_with_ranges =~ s/(.*\])/$1\[$_]/ for @$ranges;
    print $header_with_ranges, @$buffer;
}


my (@buffer, @ranges);
my $header = "";

while (<>) {
    if (/^>/) {
        my $new_header = $_;
        if (without_ranges($new_header) eq without_ranges($header)) {
            push @ranges, $new_header =~ /\[([^\]]+)\]/;

        } else {
            output($header, \@ranges, \@buffer) if $header;
            $header = $new_header;
            @buffer = @ranges = ();
        }
        last if eof;

    } else {
        push @buffer, $_;
    }
}
output($header, \@ranges, \@buffer);
```

Answer (score -1):

The code from another ticket is not that helpful, and a bit ... inoptimal, frankly.
Here is one of the possible solutions, assuming that you always have ranges `[x:y]`.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my (%hash,$key,$start
    );
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (m{^(>.*?)(?:\[(\d+):(\d+)\]\.sp\.tr)?$}) {
        ($key,$start)=($1,$2);
        next;
    }
    $hash{$key}{$start}.=$_;
}

for my $key (sort keys %hash) {
      my $keyref=$hash{$key};
      printf "%ssp.tr\n%s\n", $key, join (''
                                , map { $keyref->{$_}} sort {$a<=>$b} keys %$keyref
                                );
}

__DATA__
>303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:126].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
EEKKTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVI
KNVQ

>IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
>IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[65:126].sp.tr
TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVIKNVQ

>IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[1:61].sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNY
>IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.[65:119].sp.tr
TYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDC
```

---

```
>303.1_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNYEEKKTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVIKNVQ
>IGS-MLW-089sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNYTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDCAVIKNVQ
>IGS-MWI-254sA_assembled_PF3D7_1475500.sp.tr
MHHLLFIIWYIILNYYVSGQESATNFYKFIDSFASSTYISEESGSSAYDAKRAIQNNPNYTYDEELKESKEKANDLNNKLSLLTSVNVNTLDSDILKLGILPGDSYNFPANDC
```